# Moving Dates to Access Table Fields - Incorrect Dates Printed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having some issues with moving the CurrentDate and LastDayOfMonth to a table in Access for data processing

```
Dim CD As Date
Dim LDOM As Date

CD = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
'Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")
LDOM = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)

'Add Dates
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblProcess " & _
"SET tblProcess.[CurrentDate] = " & CD


CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblProcess " & _
"SET tblProcess.[DueDate] = " & LDOM

Debug.Print CD
Debug.Print LDOM
```

Everytime I Debug.Print - either the formula or the variable - it ALWAYS comes out correct.

**But what ends up on my table for both fields is "12/30/1899" Can anyone help?**

Comment: `CD = Date()` is simpler than `DateSerial` and will give you the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Test simply:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblProcess" _
  & " SET tblProcess.[CurrentDate] = #" & Format(CD, "yyyy-mm-dd")  & "#;"
```

Your original code uses SQL like this:

```
UPDATE tblProcess SET tblProcess.[CurrentDate] = 12/03/2013
```

that is BAD for Access DATETIME field.

Instead we need in final for Accesss SQL string:

```
  UPDATE tblProcess SET tblProcess.[CurrentDate] = #2013-12-03 22:00:13#;
```

#### Please stop voting up for such a small contribution, I have not said the last word, for SQL Server, we must use:

```
  UPDATE tblProcess SET CurrentDate = '2013-12-03T22:00:13';
```

Although Access and SQL Server are both Microsoft of [Bill Gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates).

Comment: Such an easy fix... I feel stupid for not knowing this hashtag necessity in regards to dates. Thanks Jacouh.

Comment: Numerous error in Access DateTime format, you are not unique... We have all passsed from this phrase.

Comment: re: "Please stop voting up" - Well, that's the first time I've seen *that*. ;) re: "for SQL Server" - (1) Please don't include extraneous information; it just confuses the issue. (2) Also, as far as I know SQL Server doesn't use backticks as table/column delimiters (that's MySQL). Just answer the Access question with an Access answer and leave it at that.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, backticks are not required if there is no space in field name. You've seen just.

Comment: @Gord Thompson Hey Hey now - I love a good explanation :) It's how we learn from mistakes and people like me stop posting these 30 second questions. Thanks everyone! <3